# Concerning the proof of an elementary theorem regarding $s = \sup A $.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Is my argument to the proposition below correct?

> **Proposition.** Assume $s\in\mathbf{R}$ is an upper bound for a set $A\subseteq R$. Then, $s = \sup A$ if and only if, for every choice of
>   $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an element $a\in A$ satisfying $s − \epsilon < a$.

*Proof.* $(\Rightarrow)$. Assume $s = \sup A$ and let $\epsilon>0$, by definition $s$ is the smallest upper bound for $A$, so $s-\epsilon$ cannot be an upper bound for $A$ consequently for some $a\in A$ we have $s-\epsilon<a$.

$(\Rightarrow).$ For the converse assume on the contrary that $s-\epsilon<a,\forall\epsilon>0$ but $s\neq\sup A$, then $s>b$ where $b$ is some upper bound of $A$ but this implies that $s-b>0$ and thus for $\epsilon =s-b$ we have $s-\epsilon = b<a$ for some $a\in A$ contradicting the fact that $b$ is an upperbound for $A$.

$\blacksquare$

---

Comment: Your proof is perfectly correct.

Comment: Remark: it should be mentioned that $A$ is a non-empty set here.

Comment: @Vera Doesn't need to be added. It is implied by either side of the equivalence if any of them is true. If $A=\emptyset$  then both sides are also false.

Comment: @AtifFarroq The $(\Rightarrow)$ (oops! the second part. In your question both point to the right) part is not properly structured. $s-\epsilon<a,\ \forall \epsilon>0$ is read as a single $a$ that satisfies the inequality for all $\epsilon>0$. This is neither the right-hand side of the equivalence, nor its negation. The right-hand side is $\forall \epsilon>0\exists a\in A,\ s-\epsilon <a$, with the quantified variables in that order.

Comment: @minghan You are correct. Actually I overlooked that the proposition started with "Assume $s\in\mathbb R$ is..." so I left open the possibility that $s=-\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is correct, but I have two remarks:

1. The second $\Rightarrow$ should be a $\Leftarrow$ (this is a minor remark, of course).
2. There's a quantifier missing in the second proof. It should be $(\forall\varepsilon>0)\color{red}{(\exists a\in A)}:s-\varepsilon<a$.